# Como copiar o conteúdo de um code parameter hint?

Tags: delphi, funções, ide

Em Delphi, quando pressionamos a combinação `CTRL+SHIFT+ESPAÇO` após os parênteses de uma função, a IDE traz um *code parameter hint*, dizendo os campos que devem ser informados para aquela função.

Gostaria de saber se há uma forma de copiar todo este *parameter hint* para uma String ou TEdit, para que eu possa usá-lo como um auxiliar de consulta.

Por exemplo, ao pressionar o botão *FormatFloat*, o programa me mostra o texto do hint parameter desta função (no caso, `FormatFloat(const Format: string; Value: Extended)`)

Aceito também qualquer alternativa que me permita exibir as variáveis utilizadas na chamada de uma função.

Comment: Acredito que não tenha como, pois, isto é um recurso da IDE, que só é possível acessa-los em Design.